# How to mount an exterior light that doesn't cover the junction box

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, exterior, junction

I'm trying to mount this light on the exterior of a house, but it doesn't cover the hole like the existing lights do.

In some places there's an existing light that's mounted directly to a junction box, and in others, I'm installing a light for the first time.

How should a light like this be mounted in a way that's up to code and prevents water from entering the house?

[image: LED security light]

Comment: Agree w/ DanielG (but not enough points to vote).  In general, all connnections must be inside a box, so put up a cover plate and an outdoor-rated junction box.

Comment: Thanks! Going to take the recommendation on the other question's answer and get a different light.